# Modifying an already installed JNLP application

Tags: jar, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm trying to modify an application that was deployed with JNLP onto my PC. However, when I try to replace the existing application's JAR with my new jar, it fails to lookup `javax.jnlp.SingleInstanceService` and `javax.jnlp.BasicService`.

I've already signed the main JAR file with my own key pair (not the original one), but it still does not work.

The following two lines throw `UnavailableServiceException` (uninitialised).

```
BasicService lookup = (BasicService)ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.BasicService");

SingleInstanceService singleInstanceService = (SingleInstanceService)ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.SingleInstanceService");
```

On the unmodified JAR (which is run with `java.exe -cp SomeJar.jar`), no exceptions are thrown. I am certain that this is a signature issue, as even a resigned file with no other modifications still has this issue.

Is there any way I can replicate this on my modified JAR (perhaps by adding it's keystore certificate to some file)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in jar signing. To use JNLP API you should start your jar via jnlp file.

Syntax for running jnlp file is: javaws your_jnlp_file

Your jar should be registered in resources container inside your jnlp file, and your jar should be deployed as part of your web aplication.
You are starting your jar as standard jar.
The reason why the old jar did not result in error, most possibly because it had simply handled UnavailableServiceException.